# How to correct $ mark in CSS file?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, transform

I have CSS const in my project and then I insert the "$" sign in the last line it shows error. How I can fix it?

```
const NavBox = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => { return (
<div
  css={css`
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      flex-direction: column;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      padding-top: 10vh;
      background-color: #fff;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
      top: 8vh;
      left: ${props => (props.open ? "-100%" : "0")};
    }
  `}
  {...props}
></div>
```

)
}

Comment: Why it is a lambda? Shouldn't it just be a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lambda and just do:

```css
left: ${props.open ? "-100%" : "0"};
```